# cardinality of elements in a "semiring minus multiplicative identity"

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, model-theory

In a theory that has all axioms of semiring except multiplicative identity axiom, will there be a model of the theory that has infinite elements? The model must violate multiplicative identity axiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, take $2 \mathbb{Z}$ or $2 \mathbb{N}$. With products and other standard constructions you can construct as many examples as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick any infinite ring.

Comment: I forgot to write one restriction.